# Issue using Kandy in Android apps

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I wanted to implement charts in my android app, so i find [Kandy](https://kotlin.github.io/kandy/welcome.html), a library for kotlin. I tried to use it, but after lots of problem that i solved adding exclusions and mergers in the build.gradle file, an another problem pop up. Can anyone tell me how to implement Kandy in Android apps, with gradle and using compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kandy is not a library designed for being included in an Android project, therefore the issues you're experiencing are expected.

If your requirement is to draw charts in Android, you should probably look at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart or other libraries natively written in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: MPAndroidChart is an old library, and doesn't support Compose. Also, the documentation is unreachable.

Comment: you can wrap MPAndroidChart inside an AndroidView in Compose. I saw doing this in big projects and works very good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just comment, but don't have the rep yet; in response to Lino, this quote is from the Kandy docs:

"Using the Kandy library is possible in Kotlin projects on the JVM managed by Gradle."

(Source: https://kotlin.github.io/kandy/kandy-with-gradle.html#plotting-a-simple-example)

Having said this, I was experimenting with Kandy in an Android app before Christmas, and couldn't hash through the build issues I was getting, so decided to give it a few months to settle down.  Will be trying again soon.